# Wordpress Category Page Navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation, categories

my problem is that I can navigate between Blog pages and posts but I cant navigate between the category pages.

My code looks like that:

```
<div class="previous-page">
            <?php 
                if(is_single()){ 
                    previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<div title="%title">&lsaquo;</div>') ); 
                } else {
                    previous_posts_link( __('&lsaquo;') );
                }
             ?>
        </div>
```

and I have the same code for the next_post/next_posts.
I thougt that the previous code also covers the category.
So what I am missing?

Greetings and Thanks 
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code which I currently use for all my themes:

This goes in your functions.php file:

```
function show_posts_nav() {
global $wp_query;
return ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1);
}
```

Then in your template files use this to show the navigation:

```
<?php if (show_posts_nav()) : ?>
<div class='navigation'>
<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: that doesn't help me, it still dont show me the previous posts link in the category

Comment: Does your theme have a categories.php file? If so, is the code for navigation in it?

Comment: Yes I got the category.php file, but the navigation is in the sidebar. That means I got the previous link in the left sidebar and the next link in the right sidebar. When I am on the home site it work the links are showing up. And if I am on the single page it works also the page see's the if(single()) condition and shows me the previous_post_link . I am asking my self if there is for the categorys maybe a other function then the previous_posts_link. I am sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand what I mean. And again thx for the help...